# How to capture network traffic without admin rights or 3rd party software?

Tags: networking, post, saml

I'm wondering if there is a way to capture some SAML POST tokens/data in the network traffic without using 3rd party software such as Fiddler 2, and without having admin rights to the computer to upgrade web browsers or install anything? I myself would need to remote into this persons computer, and try to capture the data that I need to look at for an issue that is presenting itself. But the persons computer I would remote into does not have admin rights to install any software of any kind, or even do updates for that matter. They are running IE8. Is there a way to capture network traffic from their computer without admin rights or 3rd party software?

Comment: What about installing portable Firefox and using SAML tracer plugin for the portable Firefox?

Comment: Does IE8 have a developer mode that would allow you to grab POST data?

Answer (score 0):

Honoring your request to not consider 3rd party software...

Depending on user permissions available, you could try setting [IE HTTP proxy settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-internet-explorer-proxy-server-settings#1TC=windows-7) to use a remote IP you control - one presumably running a proxy/debug tool of choice. For example, you could run a small VM in a cloud such as [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?nc1=h_l2_c), run a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), etc., and inspect traffic on the user's behalf.  Most HTTP debuggers like this do support configuration to allow [remote computers to use them](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/monitorremotemachine) as proxy.